# Use of factory Class to instantiate group of related concrete classes

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, tdd, factory

For a personal project I'm currently working on, I use dependency injection and TDD as a basis for development. I also use factory classes to achieve the following:

- Separation of concern: to separate the responsibility of object creation from application logic code. Single point of object creation.
- To make unit testing easier as I can mock objects created by the factories.
- Wiring: to inject certain dependencies/services into the objects it creates without the client code having to be concerned with doing so.

I understand that generally a factory class should be responsible for instantiating one particular type and that its usefulness really becomes apparent when dynamically creating different implementations of a type at runtime, however, I'm not using the factories specifically for this purpose; my reasons are those listed above. To avoid going overkill, I have not created a separate factory class for each class but I have used factory classes to instantiate groups of related classes, such as:

```
@interface TagsFactory : NSObject

/*
 * Create a new tag with the specified name
 */
-(id<Tag>) createTagWithName:(NSString*) name;

/*
 * Create a new TagsViewController with preselected tags.
 */
-(TagsViewController*) createTagViewControllerWithSelectedTags:(NSArray*) selectedTags;

/*
 * Create a new TagsView
 */
-(TagsView*) createTagsView;

@end
```

And then if a particular class needs to construct other objects, I inject the factory class(es) responsible for those objects into the class for it to delegate object creation to.

Downsides of my approach:

- Factory classes may become highly coupled with many other classes.
- Factory classes may break single responsibility principle.

Having said this, so far this approach has worked quite well for me in terms of testability and convenience without going overboard and being swamped with factory classes.

**My questions are**:

1. Is this use of factory classes deemed as bad practice, and if so, what are the dangers/risks it may pose?
2. If my approach is bad, what would be a better way of me achieving what I want without creating a vast number of factory classes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems good to me (been doing a TDD for 1-2 years only, hah, but been programming over 12), but just so I correctly understand your options,

- What's your class hierarchy?
- Can you provide the other route you were
  talking about with using more factory classes?

Stuff you already may know: It's best practice to not construct classes inside themselves and instead use a factory, and it's acceptable practice to sometimes setup multiple levels inside a factory.

If you didn't already see some of Misko's videos, have at it. This shows the multiple layer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0#t=804

I hope the spot in vid is relevant. I scanned for about 10mins for you and couldn't get any closer :D But I was looking for the spot where they say if you have a House and a Door.. how do you construct both? In a house factory or both houseFactory and doorFactory?

oh, better links: starting [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0#t=1165) and one [single build method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0#t=1287)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response. To answer your questions: a) the classes created by a given factory are only related via the function they serve, such as tagging in my example. There is no specific hierarchy amongst them; b) the other option would've been to have each factory class dedicated only to creating one particular type (single responsibility), but this would mean a proliferation of factory classes which I wanted to avoid. So I just wanted to know if my approach of lumping the creation of related objects into one factory class was suitable. Thanks for the links, very useful info :)

Comment: np. let me know if there are more questions u had